# Grouping a joined result set by sort order for the same partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables which represent a relation/hierarchy:

```
A.ID  
    B.AID
        C.BID
```

DDL and [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8d8c0/8): (In real DB have more columns)

```
CREATE TABLE A
    ([ID] int, [Title] varchar(50), [Sort] int)
;    
INSERT INTO A
    ([ID], [Title], [Sort])
VALUES
    (5, 'a5', 1),
    (4, 'a4', 2),
    (7, 'a7', 3)
;

CREATE TABLE B
    ([ID] int, [AID] int, [Title] varchar(50), [Sort] int)
;    
INSERT INTO B
    ([ID], [AID], [Title], [Sort])
VALUES
    (2, 5, 'b2', 1), -- a5
    (3, 5, 'b3', 2),
    (8, 4, 'b8', 1), -- a4
    (4, 7, 'b4', 1), -- a7
    (6, 7, 'b6', 2),
    (5, 7, 'b5', 3)
;

CREATE TABLE C
    ([ID] int, [BID] int, [Title] varchar(50), [Sort] int)
;    
INSERT INTO C
    ([ID], [BID], [Title], [Sort])
VALUES
    (1, 2, 'c1', 1), -- b2
    (8, 2, 'c8', 2),
    (2, 3, 'c2', 1), -- b3
    (3, 8, 'c3', 1), -- b8
    (7, 4, 'c7', 1), -- b4
    (4, 6, 'c4', 1), -- b6
    (6, 5, 'c6', 1), -- b5
    (5, 5, 'c5', 2)
;
```

I need to get a  result-set that is grouped by the tables relations but the order is determined by the `Sort` column for each group (partition?).

I used:

```
SELECT * FROM 
A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.BID
ORDER BY A.Sort, B.Sort, C.Sort;
```

And get the **desired** result:

```
ID    Title  Sort  ID    AID   Title  Sort  ID    BID   Title  Sort
5     a5     1     2     5     b2     1     1     2     c1     1
5     a5     1     2     5     b2     1     8     2     c8     2
5     a5     1     3     5     b3     2     2     3     c2     1
4     a4     2     8     4     b8     1     3     8     c3     1
7     a7     3     4     7     b4     1     7     4     c7     1
7     a7     3     6     7     b6     2     4     6     c4     1
7     a7     3     5     7     b5     3     6     5     c6     1
7     a7     3     5     7     b5     3     5     5     c5     2
```

Or a hierarchy view with the `Sort` column:

```
a5 (1)
|__
    b2 (1)
    |__
        c1 (1)
        c8 (2)    
    b3 (2)
    |__
        c2 (1)
a4 (2)
|__
    b8 (1)
    |__
        c3 (1)

a7 (3)
|__
    b4 (1)
    |__
        c7 (1)
    b6 (2)
    |__
        c4 (1)
    b5 (3)
    |__
        c6 (1)
        c5 (2)
```

The problem begins when the `Sort` values are not "normalized". **for example** when `a5` and `a7` have `Sort`==1 (same values). or when all `A.Sort` values are set to 0 (same goes for tables `B` and `C`).

Note: By "not normalized" I mean that the `Sort` value can be *any number* in each table. e.g.

```
UPDATE A SET Sort = 0;
```

See that the grouping breaks (`a7`) and I get random results:

```
ID    Title  Sort  ID    AID   Title  Sort  ID    BID   Title  Sort
4     a4     0     8     4     b8     1     3     8     c3     1
7     a7     0     4     7     b4     1     7     4     c7     1 <-- a7
5     a5     0     2     5     b2     1     1     2     c1     1
5     a5     0     2     5     b2     1     8     2     c8     2
5     a5     0     3     5     b3     2     2     3     c2     1
7     a7     0     6     7     b6     2     4     6     c4     1 <-- a7
7     a7     0     5     7     b5     3     6     5     c6     1
7     a7     0     5     7     b5     3     5     5     c5     2
```

I want to make the best effort get the `Sort` order right, but keep the grouping/hierarchy correct. How can this be done?

I also tried:

```
ORDER BY 
  A.Sort, A.ID,
  B.Sort, B.ID,
  C.Sort, C.ID;
```

It seems to works. But somehow, that does not feel right to me.
I'm almost sure the solution is *something like*

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID, B.ID, C.ID ORDER BY A.Sort, B.Sort, C.Sort)
```

but I'm unable to get the correct result.

---

**EDIT #1**: I think this should work, but I still need to test as I'm not sure:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.Sort) s1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY B.Sort) s2,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.ID ORDER BY C.Sort) s3,
  * 
FROM 
  A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
  INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.BID  
  ORDER by s1, s2, s3
```

**EDIT #2**: EDIT #1 did not work as expected after testing. the only thing that does *seems* to work is a simple:

```
ORDER BY A.Sort, A.ID, 
         B.Sort, B.ID, 
         C.Sort, C.ID; -- actually the C.ID is not needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.BID
ORDER BY CASE WHEN A.Sort = 0 THEN A.ID ELSE A.Sort END,
         CASE WHEN B.Sort = 0 THEN B.ID ELSE B.Sort END,
         CASE WHEN C.Sort = 0 THEN C.ID ELSE C.Sort END
```

Edit for random numbers- Try below

```
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.ID,A.Sort) AS RNK1 
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY B.ID,B.Sort) AS RNK2
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C.ID,C.Sort) AS RNK3
FROM         
A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.BID
ORDER BY RNK1,RNK2,RNK3
```

Comment: Yes, but this "fails" to get the correct result set for a normalized tables. the Order should be the first, for each partition of IDs.

Comment: Actually if I change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY A.Sort,A.ID` for the 3 tables it seems to produce the correct results. still trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the 'grouping' you want to keep, you can do this with conditional ordering on id or title, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
       INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.BID
ORDER BY CASE WHEN A.Sort = 0 THEN A.ID ELSE A.Sort END, 
         CASE WHEN B.Sort = 0 THEN B.ID ELSE B.Sort END, 
         CASE WHEN C.Sort = 0 THEN C.ID ELSE C.Sort END;
```

This way it will only sort by id, if the sort value is zero. 
You could also get MAX and MIN sort-values via a subquery and check wether they are equal.

Update: Example with MAX/MIN aggregations:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
       INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.BID
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(Sort) amax, MIN(Sort) amin FROM A) aggA ON 1 = 1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(Sort) bmax, MIN(Sort) bmin FROM A) aggB ON 1 = 1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(Sort) cmax, MIN(Sort) cmin FROM A) aggC ON 1 = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN amax = amin THEN A.ID ELSE A.Sort END, 
         CASE WHEN bmax = bmin THEN B.ID ELSE B.Sort END, 
         CASE WHEN cmax = cmin THEN C.ID ELSE C.Sort END;
```

Update2: 
This attempt counts the unique sort-values and ids and checks wether they are the same. If they are different this means that two or more ids have the same sort-value and therefore sorts by the id.
Maybe this is closer to the solution you need

```
SELECT * 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.AID
       INNER JOIN C ON B.ID = C.BID
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Sort) sorts, COUNT(ID) ids FROM A) aggA ON 1=1
       ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN aggA.sorts <> aggA.ids THEN A.ID ELSE A.Sort END,
         ...
         ;
```

Comment: 0 was meant to be an example. it could be any number.

Comment: Like I said, you could use max/min checks or similiar as well. I have updated the answer with such an example. If you want to keep the right order, if the Sort-Columns are completely messed up, I don't think this is possible. But I love to be proofed wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the code... maybe it should be `CASE WHEN amax = amin THEN A.ID, A.Sort`...? or you assume each `Sort` in the group will be the same?

Comment: When the amax = amin condition is met it means, that all sort-values in table A are the same, so there is no point in adding the A.Sort to the order by clause then

Comment: I think that `ORDER BY A.Sort, A.ID, 
         B.Sort, B.ID, 
         C.Sort, C.ID;` actually works... Let me check your second code.

Comment: In your second example, if I change `A` insert from `VALUES
    (5, 'a5', 1),
    (4, 'a4', 2),
    (7, 'a7', 3)` to `VALUES
    (5, 'a5', 1),
    (4, 'a4', 2),
    (7, 'a7', 1)` (note the a7 `Sort` changed to `1`) - it will display `a4` before the 2 others.

Comment: You need to clarify what do you mean by "not normalized". Are alle Sorts of one Group the same? Are they all different? Is it okay if one Sort is in several groups? If so, You could change my second Update and group the subquery by Id.

Comment: "not normalized" simply means that the `Sort` is not correct or missing. anything that will not show (or break) correct grouping/sort order when using `ORDER BY A.Sort, B.Sort, C.Sort`. each hierarchy ideally has a `Sort` starting from `1`. in fact my next step is to UPDATE the tables and set the correct `Sort` order based on the current data.